# Superlinear Problems Partial differential equations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$, with $N \geq 3$, be open and bounded, $h \in L^{\infty}(\Omega) \backslash\{0\}$ and $2<p<2^{*}$, and consider the problem
$$
\begin{cases}-\Delta u=h(x)|u|^{p-2} u & \text { in } \Omega \\ u=0 & \text { on } \partial \Omega\end{cases}
$$
Prove that if $h(x) \leq 0$ a.e. in $\Omega$, the problem has no nontrivial solutions.

\textbf{My attempt:}

I consider the hypotheses of the problem and proceed by contradiction. Assuming that the problem has at least one non-trivial solution.

Then, since (1) has at least one solution then we consider the associated functional whose critical points are the solution to the problem. Let $I:H_0^1(\Omega)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2dx-\frac{1}{p}\int_\Omega h(x)|u|^pdx$$
Let us note that the functional is well defined since $h\in L^\infty(\Omega)-\{0\}$ and therefore the integral is convergent and is differentiable. Now let's look at coercivity,
\begin{align*}
  I(tu) & =\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega|\nabla tu|^2dx-\frac{1}{p}\int_\Omega h(x)|tu|^pdx\\
       & = \frac{t^2}{2}\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2dx-\frac{t^p}{p}\int_\Omega h(x)|u|^pdx\rightarrow-\infty
\end{align*}
If $t\to\infty$ so at least we have a solution. My question is where can I find the contradiction?

Comment: Can you not multiply the equation by $u$, and integrate by parts to get a nonnegative value on the left, and a nonpositive value on the right? Then you are done I think

Answer (score 2):

The functional $I$ in your calculations is convex due to $h\ge0$. Due to the presence of the $|\nabla u|^2$-term it is even strongly convex on $H^1$ (by Poincare inequality). Hence, the minimization problem and the pde have at most one solution, which is $u=0$.